# Rails 3 : route a resource to another name

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a CRUD controller for a model.

Doing `resources :foo` allows me to route on `/foo/:id`, etc. for calling actions.

I want add a route for a translation of 'foo' in another language. Let's say 'toto'.
So I want all the `/toto/:id`, etc., routes to act exactly like the `/foo/:id`, etc., routes.

How may I achieve that?

Answer (score 39):

You can add a new resource and specify foo as the controller:

```
resources :toto, :controller=>"foo"
```

This will point all the actions to "foo", but there is a gotcha.  I think you will run into problems with the links on the page, if you are using foo_url or something like that.  So you would have to figure out a way to create the URLs dymanically based on the controller in "request.path".

Comment: Any idea as to how we can get the views to load up from `views/toto` instead of `views/foo`?

Comment: `resources :toto, :controller=>"foo", :path => "toto"`

Answer (score 25):

This will let you rename paths seen by the user but keep the original name of your controllers in the code:

```
scope(:path_names => { :new => "neu", :edit => "bearbeiten" }) do
  resources :categories, :path => "kategorien"
end
```

[From the Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths)

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly, you want to just use another path.

```
resources :foo, path: 'toto'
```

Now you will have:

```
GET /toto          foo#index
GET /toto/:id      foo#show
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something close to this using scope:

```
scope ':language/' do
  resources :foo, controller: 'bar_controller'
end
```

This make your bar_controller a resource to anything/foo, where anything gets passed as the :language parameter.

so:

- en_US/foo
- de_DE/foo
- ja_JP/foo

all get handled by bar_controller, with the normal resource mapping, and you get params[:language] in the controller for free.