# Rails routes change URL with ressources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my routes:

```
resources :collection_pages, :only => [:show, :index]
```

Right now its going to wwww.mysite.com/collection_pages for index

and `collection_pages/:id` for show

I need it to go to `/collection`s instead for index

and `/collection/:id` for show

I tried `path: :collections` , but its not behaving as I'd like.

What's the best way to achieve this using ressources?

Comment: Why not just change it to `resources :collection` and modify the controller name?

Comment: Already have it implemented through out the app using that route

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3676809/368167) answer, it might help a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676809/368167) @Tamer.Shlash notes, you could use custom matchers in your routes file:

```
match '/collection', to: 'collection_pages#index', as: 'collection_index'
match '/collection/:id', to: 'collection_pages#show', as: 'collection_show'
```

Adding the as: 'xxxx' to the match allows you to use friendly path and url helpers in your views:

```
redirect_to collection_index_path
```